# NotifyOfPropertyChange Not Updating

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 3 textboxes, First one is Duration, SEcond is Amount and the third is the total which is just Duration * Amount. I'm trying to implement this using NotifyOfPropertyChange INSTEAD of OnPropertyChange. I'm wondering if I can get help towards why it's not updating.

```
public int? SebDuration
{
    get
    {
        return _seb.SEBDuration;
    }
    set
    {
        _seb.SEBDuration = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("SebDuration");
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("SebTotal");
    }
}
public decimal? SebAmountPer
{
    get
    {
        return _seb.SEBAmountPer;
    }
    set
    {
        _seb.SEBAmountPer = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("SebAmountPer");
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("SebTotal");
    }
}
 public decimal? SebTotal
{
    get
    {
        if (_seb.SEBTotal.HasValue)
        {
            return _seb.SEBTotal;
        }
        if (SebAmountPer.HasValue && SebDuration.HasValue)
        {
            return SebAmountPer.Value * SebDuration.Value;
        }
        return null;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_seb.SEBTotal != value)
        {
            _seb.SEBTotal = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("SebTotal");
        }
    }
}
```

If I replace each NotifyOfPropertyChange with OnPropertyChanged, it will work.

Comment: What is this `NotifyOfPropertyChange` method? Did you create it yourself? It's not a standard method, in any case, so we can't help you without seeing its code...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Its likely Caliburn Micro. Not standard WPF, but also not custom.

Comment: Did you set IsNotifying to false somewhere in your code?

Comment: No, very odd. Works with Onpropertychanged

Answer (score 0):

`NotifyOfPropertyChanged` (a caliburn micro concept) expects a lambda expression that returns the property to notify for. It then uses reflection to get the actual string. You actually want to call it like this:

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SebTotal);
```

The code you have likely compiles because the framework just needs an `object` (which `String` is), but then fails at the reflection part (obviously).

Comment: Actually, it doesn't use reflection; the lambda parameter is an expression tree, not a delegate ;). But anyway, since there is also an overload of NotifyOfPropertyChange that takes a string, I don't think that's the reason why it doesn't work...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque This may be out of date, but it sure *looks* like reflection... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/780cf8ef-4340-4e27-b240-7beef43c03a2/notifyofpropertychange-name?forum=silverlightmvvm

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, well, stricly speaking, you're right, but there is actually no reflection cost, because the property is already resolved at compile time. At runtime, it just accesses the `Name` property of the MemberInfo.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, thanks for the info. I imagine thats the same thing the new [CallerMemberName] attribute does. Thanks again!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, actually, the [CallerMemberName] attribute passes the property name to the method, at compile time, so there is no reflection involved at all. It's exactly the same as if you had passed the name yourself.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, Learned something new again :) Thanks for all the insight!